# Why is the dynamodb performance different between these queries?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have 3 tables:

```
table 1
=======
Size 458.54 MB
Count  2,887,152

table 2
=======
Size 161.05 MB
Count  1,060,444

table 3
=======
Size 4.10 GB
Count  2,629,162
```

I've provisioned all 3 tables to 500 read capacity units (RCU), and paginate through 20 pages using python2.7 and a simple boto3.scan().

Why is the duration so different among them, while consuming exactly the same RCU's?

```
table 1
=======
seconds: 65.7738468647
row_count: 131925
scanned_count: 131925
consumed_capacity: 2570.0

table 2
=======
seconds: 97.8232300282
row_count: 138092
scanned_count: 138092
consumed_capacity: 2570.0

table 3
=======
seconds: 37.8384461403
row_count: 13416
scanned_count: 13416
consumed_capacity: 2571.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the boto3 response parser. Larger, more complicated objects will take longer to parse. I imagine if you look at the objects in each of those tables you'll see a correlation between more complicated objects and query speed. Transfer time also will impact things significantly.